# Pass multiple JSON data in Request Body of Postman and Get it into Java using undertow API

Tags: java, json, api, undertow

I want to get multiple JSON data which I am passing into Postman in Body as Json format.
If I am passing single json data like

```
{
   "Name":"Albert",
   "PhoneNo":"9846758098",
   "Country":"USA"
}
```

then I am getting the data in java but I want to pass multiple JSON data in postman like this

```
{
   "Count":"2",
   "Data":[
      {
         "Name":"Albert",
         "PhoneNo":"9846758098",
         "Country":"USA"
      },
      {
         "Name":"Yash",
         "PhoneNo":"9847898098",
         "Country":"IN"
      }
   ]
}
```

So for getting this data in java what i need to do

[This is what i used to get single JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VseTj.png)

[Now I want to get this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EEUf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your VatData class should be as:

```
 class VatData{
        String Count;
        List<MyData> Data;
    }
```

and MyData should be as:

```
class MyData {
     String PhoneNo;
     String Country;
     String Name;
  }
```

Comment: I guess this answer is not complete(?)

Comment: yes, "Enter" suddenly pressed while typing process, I've edited it, u can check agaun now)

Comment: I did what you suggested but getting null value in the log.